# Updating data in gridview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, vb.net-to-c#

First I populated the datagridview by data of sqlserver 2008 database table, now i have muliple rows in datagridview containing data, i am trying to update any row but, in the database table it replaces other rows data by the row data that iam trying to update
 the code for update statement is given below

Plz help me

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update EmployeeDetail Set Salary = '" &      
dgvEmpDetail.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value & "', Experience ='" &  
dgvEmpDetail.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value & "', Skills='" &  
dgvEmpDetail.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value 
& "' where Emp_ID = '" & dgvEmpDetail.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value & "'", con)
con.Open()                                                         
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()     
con.Close()
```

Comment: This is not about `c#`. It is `vb.net`. Don't add irrelevant tags.

Comment: with this code, you probably update the first row only. and your question is not clear enough i perhaps.

Comment: i need to update multiple rows, but when iam trying to update any row's cell value then all the other records are replaced by the row values that iam trying to update

Comment: Look for bulk updates on Google. You will find some useful help.

Answer (score 0):

You've hard coded the row - dgvEmpDetail.Rows(0).

I imagine you are calling this in a loop.  You should do something like:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvEmpDetail.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update EmployeeDetail Set Salary = '" & dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "', Experience ='" & dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value & "', Skills='" & dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value()& "' where Emp_ID = '" & dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "'", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    Next
```

Your code is susceptible to SQL injection.  You should put the update SQL in to a stored procedure - its faster and safer!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load()

    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      ' Create a new table.
      Dim taskTable As New DataTable("TaskList")

      ' Create the columns.
      taskTable.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
      taskTable.Columns.Add("Description", GetType(String))
      taskTable.Columns.Add("IsComplete", GetType(Boolean))

      'Add data to the new table.
      For i = 0 To 19
        Dim tableRow = taskTable.NewRow()
        tableRow("Id") = i
        tableRow("Description") = "Task " + i.ToString()
        tableRow("IsComplete") = False
        taskTable.Rows.Add(tableRow)
      Next

      'Persist the table in the Session object.
      Session("TaskTable") = taskTable

      'Bind data to the GridView control.
      BindData()
    End If

  End Sub

  Protected Sub TaskGridView_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    TaskGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
  End Sub

  Protected Sub TaskGridView_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    'Set the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
  End Sub

  Protected Sub TaskGridView_RowCancelingEdit()
    'Reset the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = -1
    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
  End Sub

  Protected Sub TaskGridView_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    'Retrieve the table from the session object.
    Dim dt = CType(Session("TaskTable"), DataTable)

    'Update the values.
    Dim row = TaskGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Id") = (CType((row.Cells(1).Controls(0)), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("Description") = (CType((row.Cells(2).Controls(0)), TextBox)).Text
    dt.Rows(row.DataItemIndex)("IsComplete") = (CType((row.Cells(3).Controls(0)), CheckBox)).Checked

    'Reset the edit index.
    TaskGridView.EditIndex = -1

    'Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData()
  End Sub

  Private Sub BindData()
    TaskGridView.DataSource = Session("TaskTable")
    TaskGridView.DataBind()
  End Sub

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a access connection with textbox as data feeder to database change it to SQL if u want. The code is:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form2
    Dim conaccess As New OleDbConnection
    Dim conreader As OleDbDataReader
    Dim concmd As New OleDbCommand


    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        DataGridView1.EditMode = False
        conaccess.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=d:\vijay.mdb"
        conaccess.Open()
        loadGrid()
    End Sub

    Private Sub loadGrid()
        Dim access As String
        access = "select * from vijay"
        Dim DataTab As New DataTable
        Dim DataAdap As New OleDbDataAdapter(access, conaccess)
        DataAdap.Fill(DataTab)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTab
    End Sub

    Private Sub new_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click

        Dim no As String
        no = "select Max(ID) from vijay"
        Dim concmd As New OleDbCommand(no, conaccess)
        conreader = concmd.ExecuteReader
        If (conreader.Read) Then
            If (IsDBNull(conreader(0))) Then
                id_txt.Text = "1"
            Else
                id_txt.Text = conreader(0) + 1
            End If
            name_txt.Clear()
            branch_txt.Clear()
            age_txt.Clear()
            class_txt.Clear()
            gen_txt.Clear()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Dim i As Integer

        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        Try
            id_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
            name_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
            class_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
            gen_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
            branch_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value
            age_txt.Text = DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub


    Private Sub del_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles del_btn.Click
        Dim delcmd As New OleDbCommand("delete from vijay where id=" & id_txt.Text & " ", conaccess)
        delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record is deleted")
        loadGrid()
        id_txt.Clear()
        name_txt.Clear()
        branch_txt.Clear()
        age_txt.Clear()
        class_txt.Clear()
        gen_txt.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
        Dim access As String = String.Format("INSERT INTO vijay (Name,Class,Branch,Gender,Age) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", name_txt.Text, class_txt.Text, branch_txt.Text, gen_txt.Text, age_txt.Text)
        concmd.Connection = conaccess
        concmd.CommandText = access
        concmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Record Successfully Saved")
        loadGrid()
        id_txt.Clear()
        name_txt.Clear()
        branch_txt.Clear()
        age_txt.Clear()
        class_txt.Clear()
        gen_txt.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub up_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles up_btn.Click
        Dim access As String
        access = "UPDATE vijay SET Name = '" & name_txt.Text & "', Age = '" & age_txt.Text & "', Gender ='" & gen_txt.Text & "' , Branch ='" & branch_txt.Text & "' , Class = '" & class_txt.Text & "' where id=" & id_txt.Text & ""
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(access, conaccess)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        loadGrid()
        id_txt.Clear()
        name_txt.Clear()
        branch_txt.Clear()
        age_txt.Clear()
        class_txt.Clear()
        gen_txt.Clear()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Use looping and parameter (to handle sql injection):

```
 con.Open() 'Open connection to database

 'Looping throung dgv
 For i As Integer = 0 To dgvEmpDetail.Rows.Count - 1
    If IsDBNull(dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells("Emp_ID").Value) Then Exit For
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update EmployeeDetail Set [Salary] = ?, [Experience]=?, [Skills]=? WHERE [Emp_ID] =?", con)

    With cmd.Parameters
       .AddWithValue("@Salary", dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells("Salary").Value )
       .AddWithValue("@Experience", dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells("Experience").Value )
       .AddWithValue("@Skills", dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells("Skills").Value )
       .AddWithValue("@Emp_ID", dgvEmpDetail.Rows(i).Cells("Emp_ID").Value )
    End With
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Next i

con.Close() 'Close connection with Database
```